# Swap title and tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace, greasemonkey, swap

I have html code in a 3rd party website:

```
<div class="info_texts">
  <a href="down.php?action=details&amp;id=111"
  onclick="get_file(111); return false;"
  title="TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT">

    <nobr>TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO LONGER TEXT, TOO...</nobr>
  </a>
</div>
```

Now I see truncated text (Short text...) without whole of text (Full text, without ...)

I wanna swap `title=""` with `<nobr></nobr>` with javacript (greasemonkey script)

In website have a lot of `<div class="info_texts">` so should replace all of tags.

Thank you!

Comment: can I answer it with plain javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code:

```
// get all a tags with title inside div info_texts
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.info_texts a[title]');

// loop through them
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {

  // use one of these
  // --------------------------------


  // 1- replaces the entire content including <nobr>
  a[i].textContent = a[i].title; 


  // 2- if you want to keep <nobr>
  var nobr = a[i].querySelector('nobr');
  if (nobr) { nobr.textContent = a[i].title; }


  // 3- combination of both above methods
  var nobr = a[i].querySelector('nobr');
  if (nobr) { nobr.textContent = a[i].title; }
  else { a[i].textContent = a[i].title; }


  // 4- more error checking, in case title is blank
  if (!a[i].title.trim()) { continue; }
  var nobr = a[i].querySelector('nobr');
  if (nobr) { nobr.textContent = a[i].title; }
  else { a[i].textContent = a[i].title; }
}
```

Comment: The site have a lot of "info_texts" divs, but your code can read the first only, not all of divs.

Comment: @user7339814 ... oops, there is a typo... fixed